# This regex to strip punctuation also incorrectly makes the word Báenou into Benou

Tags: javascript, regex, string, sanitization, punctuation

The goal of this regex is to remove punctuation characters:

```
var myTxt = "Welcome, Visitor: The Royal Kingdom Of Báenou";
myTxt = myTxt.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+/g, '').replace('/ {2,}/',' ');
alert(myTxt);
```

So the text above should become this:

```
Welcome Visitor The Royal Kingdom Of Báenou
```

But instead it incorrectly drops the `á` in `Báenou` to produce this:

```
Welcome Visitor The Royal Kingdom Of Benou
```

What's the simplest change I could make to the regex to make it work as intended?

Answer (score 10):

Your problem is that you are dropping anything that is not in a "whitelist" which you define as all (non-accented) letters, numbers, and space and replacing it with an empty string.

Since á is not in `[a-z]`, it will be considered "punctuation" and removed.

What you need is to filter for things that are in a "blacklist" and proactively replace those.

Try a regex like this:

```
myTxt = myTxt.replace(/['";:,.\/?\\-]/g, '');
```

Answer (score 2):

The `á` is matched and removed as it is neither of `a`–`z`, `A`–`Z`, `0`–`9` or  . You might want to use some more extensive set of allowed characters like *any Unicode letter*. But since JavaScript does not support Unicode character properties, you will need to specify the ranges yourself:

```
/[^\u0061-\u007A\u00AA\u00B5\u00BA\u00DF-\u00F6\u00F8-\u00FF\u0101\u0103\u0105\u0107\u0109\u010B\u010D\u010F\u0111\u0113\u0115\u0117\u0119\u011B\u011D\u011F\u0121\u0123\u0125\u0127\u0129\u012B\u012D\u012F\u0131\u0133\u0135\u0137\u0138\u013A\u013C\u013E\u0140\u0142\u0144\u0146\u0148\u0149\u014B\u014D\u014F\u0151\u0153\u0155\u0157\u0159\u015B\u015D\u015F\u0161\u0163\u0165\u0167\u0169\u016B\u016D\u016F\u0171\u0173\u0175\u0177\u017A\u017C\u017E-\u0180\u0183\u0185\u0188\u018C\u018D\u0192\u0195\u0199-\u019B\u019E\u01A1\u01A3\u01A5\u01A8\u01AA\u01AB\u01AD\u01B0\u01B4\u01B6\u01B9\u01BA\u01BD-\u01BF\u01C6\u01C9\u01CC\u01CE\u01D0\u01D2\u01D4\u01D6\u01D8\u01DA\u01DC\u01DD\u01DF\u01E1\u01E3\u01E5\u01E7\u01E9\u01EB\u01ED\u01EF\u01F0\u01F3\u01F5\u01F9\u01FB\u01FD\u01FF\u0201\u0203\u0205\u0207\u0209\u020B\u020D\u020F\u0211\u0213\u0215\u0217\u0219\u021B\u021D\u021F\u0221\u0223\u0225\u0227\u0229\u022B\u022D\u022F\u0231\u0233-\u0239\u023C\u023F\u0240\u0242\u0247\u0249\u024B\u024D\u024F-\u0293\u0295-\u02AF\u0371\u0373\u0377\u037B-\u037D\u0390\u03AC-\u03CE\u03D0\u03D1\u03D5-\u03D7\u03D9\u03DB\u03DD\u03DF\u03E1\u03E3\u03E5\u03E7\u03E9\u03EB\u03ED\u03EF-\u03F3\u03F5\u03F8\u03FB\u03FC\u0430-\u045F\u0461\u0463\u0465\u0467\u0469\u046B\u046D\u046F\u0471\u0473\u0475\u0477\u0479\u047B\u047D\u047F\u0481\u048B\u048D\u048F\u0491\u0493\u0495\u0497\u0499\u049B\u049D\u049F\u04A1\u04A3\u04A5\u04A7\u04A9\u04AB\u04AD\u04AF\u04B1\u04B3\u04B5\u04B7\u04B9\u04BB\u04BD\u04BF\u04C2\u04C4\u04C6\u04C8\u04CA\u04CC\u04CE\u04CF\u04D1\u04D3\u04D5\u04D7\u04D9\u04DB\u04DD\u04DF\u04E1\u04E3\u04E5\u04E7\u04E9\u04EB\u04ED\u04EF\u04F1\u04F3\u04F5\u04F7\u04F9\u04FB\u04FD\u04FF\u0501\u0503\u0505\u0507\u0509\u050B\u050D\u050F\u0511\u0513\u0515\u0517\u0519\u051B\u051D\u051F\u0521\u0523\u0525\u0561-\u0587\u1D00-\u1D2B\u1D62-\u1D77\u1D79-\u1D9A\u1E01\u1E03\u1E05\u1E07\u1E09\u1E0B\u1E0D\u1E0F\u1E11\u1E13\u1E15\u1E17\u1E19\u1E1B\u1E1D\u1E1F\u1E21\u1E23\u1E25\u1E27\u1E29\u1E2B\u1E2D\u1E2F\u1E31\u1E33\u1E35\u1E37\u1E39\u1E3B\u1E3D\u1E3F\u1E41\u1E43\u1E45\u1E47\u1E49\u1E4B\u1E4D\u1E4F\u1E51\u1E53\u1E55\u1E57\u1E59\u1E5B\u1E5D\u1E5F\u1E61\u1E63\u1E65\u1E67\u1E69\u1E6B\u1E6D\u1E6F\u1E71\u1E73\u1E75\u1E77\u1E79\u1E7B\u1E7D\u1E7F\u1E81\u1E83\u1E85\u1E87\u1E89\u1E8B\u1E8D\u1E8F\u1E91\u1E93\u1E95-\u1E9D\u1E9F\u1EA1\u1EA3\u1EA5\u1EA7\u1EA9\u1EAB\u1EAD\u1EAF\u1EB1\u1EB3\u1EB5\u1EB7\u1EB9\u1EBB\u1EBD\u1EBF\u1EC1\u1EC3\u1EC5\u1EC7\u1EC9\u1ECB\u1ECD\u1ECF\u1ED1\u1ED3\u1ED5\u1ED7\u1ED9\u1EDB\u1EDD\u1EDF\u1EE1\u1EE3\u1EE5\u1EE7\u1EE9\u1EEB\u1EED\u1EEF\u1EF1\u1EF3\u1EF5\u1EF7\u1EF9\u1EFB\u1EFD\u1EFF-\u1F07\u1F10-\u1F15\u1F20-\u1F27\u1F30-\u1F37\u1F40-\u1F45\u1F50-\u1F57\u1F60-\u1F67\u1F70-\u1F7D\u1F80-\u1F87\u1F90-\u1F97\u1FA0-\u1FA7\u1FB0-\u1FB4\u1FB6\u1FB7\u1FBE\u1FC2-\u1FC4\u1FC6\u1FC7\u1FD0-\u1FD3\u1FD6\u1FD7\u1FE0-\u1FE7\u1FF2-\u1FF4\u1FF6\u1FF7\u210A\u210E\u210F\u2113\u212F\u2134\u2139\u213C\u213D\u2146-\u2149\u214E\u2184\u2C30-\u2C5E\u2C61\u2C65\u2C66\u2C68\u2C6A\u2C6C\u2C71\u2C73\u2C74\u2C76-\u2C7C\u2C81\u2C83\u2C85\u2C87\u2C89\u2C8B\u2C8D\u2C8F\u2C91\u2C93\u2C95\u2C97\u2C99\u2C9B\u2C9D\u2C9F\u2CA1\u2CA3\u2CA5\u2CA7\u2CA9\u2CAB\u2CAD\u2CAF\u2CB1\u2CB3\u2CB5\u2CB7\u2CB9\u2CBB\u2CBD\u2CBF\u2CC1\u2CC3\u2CC5\u2CC7\u2CC9\u2CCB\u2CCD\u2CCF\u2CD1\u2CD3\u2CD5\u2CD7\u2CD9\u2CDB\u2CDD\u2CDF\u2CE1\u2CE3\u2CE4\u2CEC\u2CEE\u2D00-\u2D25\uA641\uA643\uA645\uA647\uA649\uA64B\uA64D\uA64F\uA651\uA653\uA655\uA657\uA659\uA65B\uA65D\uA65F\uA663\uA665\uA667\uA669\uA66B\uA66D\uA681\uA683\uA685\uA687\uA689\uA68B\uA68D\uA68F\uA691\uA693\uA695\uA697\uA723\uA725\uA727\uA729\uA72B\uA72D\uA72F-\uA731\uA733\uA735\uA737\uA739\uA73B\uA73D\uA73F\uA741\uA743\uA745\uA747\uA749\uA74B\uA74D\uA74F\uA751\uA753\uA755\uA757\uA759\uA75B\uA75D\uA75F\uA761\uA763\uA765\uA767\uA769\uA76B\uA76D\uA76F\uA771-\uA778\uA77A\uA77C\uA77F\uA781\uA783\uA785\uA787\uA78C\uFB00-\uFB06\uFB13-\uFB17\uFF41-\uFF5A\u0041-\u005A\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00DE\u0100\u0102\u0104\u0106\u0108\u010A\u010C\u010E\u0110\u0112\u0114\u0116\u0118\u011A\u011C\u011E\u0120\u0122\u0124\u0126\u0128\u012A\u012C\u012E\u0130\u0132\u0134\u0136\u0139\u013B\u013D\u013F\u0141\u0143\u0145\u0147\u014A\u014C\u014E\u0150\u0152\u0154\u0156\u0158\u015A\u015C\u015E\u0160\u0162\u0164\u0166\u0168\u016A\u016C\u016E\u0170\u0172\u0174\u0176\u0178\u0179\u017B\u017D\u0181\u0182\u0184\u0186\u0187\u0189-\u018B\u018E-\u0191\u0193\u0194\u0196-\u0198\u019C\u019D\u019F\u01A0\u01A2\u01A4\u01A6\u01A7\u01A9\u01AC\u01AE\u01AF\u01B1-\u01B3\u01B5\u01B7\u01B8\u01BC\u01C4\u01C7\u01CA\u01CD\u01CF\u01D1\u01D3\u01D5\u01D7\u01D9\u01DB\u01DE\u01E0\u01E2\u01E4\u01E6\u01E8\u01EA\u01EC\u01EE\u01F1\u01F4\u01F6-\u01F8\u01FA\u01FC\u01FE\u0200\u0202\u0204\u0206\u0208\u020A\u020C\u020E\u0210\u0212\u0214\u0216\u0218\u021A\u021C\u021E\u0220\u0222\u0224\u0226\u0228\u022A\u022C\u022E\u0230\u0232\u023A\u023B\u023D\u023E\u0241\u0243-\u0246\u0248\u024A\u024C\u024E\u0370\u0372\u0376\u0386\u0388-\u038A\u038C\u038E\u038F\u0391-\u03A1\u03A3-\u03AB\u03CF\u03D2-\u03D4\u03D8\u03DA\u03DC\u03DE\u03E0\u03E2\u03E4\u03E6\u03E8\u03EA\u03EC\u03EE\u03F4\u03F7\u03F9\u03FA\u03FD-\u042F\u0460\u0462\u0464\u0466\u0468\u046A\u046C\u046E\u0470\u0472\u0474\u0476\u0478\u047A\u047C\u047E\u0480\u048A\u048C\u048E\u0490\u0492\u0494\u0496\u0498\u049A\u049C\u049E\u04A0\u04A2\u04A4\u04A6\u04A8\u04AA\u04AC\u04AE\u04B0\u04B2\u04B4\u04B6\u04B8\u04BA\u04BC\u04BE\u04C0\u04C1\u04C3\u04C5\u04C7\u04C9\u04CB\u04CD\u04D0\u04D2\u04D4\u04D6\u04D8\u04DA\u04DC\u04DE\u04E0\u04E2\u04E4\u04E6\u04E8\u04EA\u04EC\u04EE\u04F0\u04F2\u04F4\u04F6\u04F8\u04FA\u04FC\u04FE\u0500\u0502\u0504\u0506\u0508\u050A\u050C\u050E\u0510\u0512\u0514\u0516\u0518\u051A\u051C\u051E\u0520\u0522\u0524\u0531-\u0556\u10A0-\u10C5\u1E00\u1E02\u1E04\u1E06\u1E08\u1E0A\u1E0C\u1E0E\u1E10\u1E12\u1E14\u1E16\u1E18\u1E1A\u1E1C\u1E1E\u1E20\u1E22\u1E24\u1E26\u1E28\u1E2A\u1E2C\u1E2E\u1E30\u1E32\u1E34\u1E36\u1E38\u1E3A\u1E3C\u1E3E\u1E40\u1E42\u1E44\u1E46\u1E48\u1E4A\u1E4C\u1E4E\u1E50\u1E52\u1E54\u1E56\u1E58\u1E5A\u1E5C\u1E5E\u1E60\u1E62\u1E64\u1E66\u1E68\u1E6A\u1E6C\u1E6E\u1E70\u1E72\u1E74\u1E76\u1E78\u1E7A\u1E7C\u1E7E\u1E80\u1E82\u1E84\u1E86\u1E88\u1E8A\u1E8C\u1E8E\u1E90\u1E92\u1E94\u1E9E\u1EA0\u1EA2\u1EA4\u1EA6\u1EA8\u1EAA\u1EAC\u1EAE\u1EB0\u1EB2\u1EB4\u1EB6\u1EB8\u1EBA\u1EBC\u1EBE\u1EC0\u1EC2\u1EC4\u1EC6\u1EC8\u1ECA\u1ECC\u1ECE\u1ED0\u1ED2\u1ED4\u1ED6\u1ED8\u1EDA\u1EDC\u1EDE\u1EE0\u1EE2\u1EE4\u1EE6\u1EE8\u1EEA\u1EEC\u1EEE\u1EF0\u1EF2\u1EF4\u1EF6\u1EF8\u1EFA\u1EFC\u1EFE\u1F08-\u1F0F\u1F18-\u1F1D\u1F28-\u1F2F\u1F38-\u1F3F\u1F48-\u1F4D\u1F59\u1F5B\u1F5D\u1F5F\u1F68-\u1F6F\u1FB8-\u1FBB\u1FC8-\u1FCB\u1FD8-\u1FDB\u1FE8-\u1FEC\u1FF8-\u1FFB\u2102\u2107\u210B-\u210D\u2110-\u2112\u2115\u2119-\u211D\u2124\u2126\u2128\u212A-\u212D\u2130-\u2133\u213E\u213F\u2145\u2183\u2C00-\u2C2E\u2C60\u2C62-\u2C64\u2C67\u2C69\u2C6B\u2C6D-\u2C70\u2C72\u2C75\u2C7E-\u2C80\u2C82\u2C84\u2C86\u2C88\u2C8A\u2C8C\u2C8E\u2C90\u2C92\u2C94\u2C96\u2C98\u2C9A\u2C9C\u2C9E\u2CA0\u2CA2\u2CA4\u2CA6\u2CA8\u2CAA\u2CAC\u2CAE\u2CB0\u2CB2\u2CB4\u2CB6\u2CB8\u2CBA\u2CBC\u2CBE\u2CC0\u2CC2\u2CC4\u2CC6\u2CC8\u2CCA\u2CCC\u2CCE\u2CD0\u2CD2\u2CD4\u2CD6\u2CD8\u2CDA\u2CDC\u2CDE\u2CE0\u2CE2\u2CEB\u2CED\uA640\uA642\uA644\uA646\uA648\uA64A\uA64C\uA64E\uA650\uA652\uA654\uA656\uA658\uA65A\uA65C\uA65E\uA662\uA664\uA666\uA668\uA66A\uA66C\uA680\uA682\uA684\uA686\uA688\uA68A\uA68C\uA68E\uA690\uA692\uA694\uA696\uA722\uA724\uA726\uA728\uA72A\uA72C\uA72E\uA732\uA734\uA736\uA738\uA73A\uA73C\uA73E\uA740\uA742\uA744\uA746\uA748\uA74A\uA74C\uA74E\uA750\uA752\uA754\uA756\uA758\uA75A\uA75C\uA75E\uA760\uA762\uA764\uA766\uA768\uA76A\uA76C\uA76E\uA779\uA77B\uA77D\uA77E\uA780\uA782\uA784\uA786\uA78B\uFF21-\uFF3A\u01C5\u01C8\u01CB\u01F2\u1F88-\u1F8F\u1F98-\u1F9F\u1FA8-\u1FAF\u1FBC\u1FCC\u1FFC\u02B0-\u02C1\u02C6-\u02D1\u02E0-\u02E4\u02EC\u02EE\u0374\u037A\u0559\u0640\u06E5\u06E6\u07F4\u07F5\u07FA\u081A\u0824\u0828\u0971\u0E46\u0EC6\u10FC\u17D7\u1843\u1AA7\u1C78-\u1C7D\u1D2C-\u1D61\u1D78\u1D9B-\u1DBF\u2071\u207F\u2090-\u2094\u2C7D\u2D6F\u2E2F\u3005\u3031-\u3035\u303B\u309D\u309E\u30FC-\u30FE\uA015\uA4F8-\uA4FD\uA60C\uA67F\uA717-\uA71F\uA770\uA788\uA9CF\uAA70\uAADD\uFF70\uFF9E\uFF9F\u01BB\u01C0-\u01C3\u0294\u05D0-\u05EA\u05F0-\u05F2\u0621-\u063F\u0641-\u064A\u066E\u066F\u0671-\u06D3\u06D5\u06EE\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FC\u06FF\u0710\u0712-\u072F\u074D-\u07A5\u07B1\u07CA-\u07EA\u0800-\u0815\u0904-\u0939\u093D\u0950\u0958-\u0961\u0972\u0979-\u097F\u0985-\u098C\u098F\u0990\u0993-\u09A8\u09AA-\u09B0\u09B2\u09B6-\u09B9\u09BD\u09CE\u09DC\u09DD\u09DF-\u09E1\u09F0\u09F1\u0A05-\u0A0A\u0A0F\u0A10\u0A13-\u0A28\u0A2A-\u0A30\u0A32\u0A33\u0A35\u0A36\u0A38\u0A39\u0A59-\u0A5C\u0A5E\u0A72-\u0A74\u0A85-\u0A8D\u0A8F-\u0A91\u0A93-\u0AA8\u0AAA-\u0AB0\u0AB2\u0AB3\u0AB5-\u0AB9\u0ABD\u0AD0\u0AE0\u0AE1\u0B05-\u0B0C\u0B0F\u0B10\u0B13-\u0B28\u0B2A-\u0B30\u0B32\u0B33\u0B35-\u0B39\u0B3D\u0B5C\u0B5D\u0B5F-\u0B61\u0B71\u0B83\u0B85-\u0B8A\u0B8E-\u0B90\u0B92-\u0B95\u0B99\u0B9A\u0B9C\u0B9E\u0B9F\u0BA3\u0BA4\u0BA8-\u0BAA\u0BAE-\u0BB9\u0BD0\u0C05-\u0C0C\u0C0E-\u0C10\u0C12-\u0C28\u0C2A-\u0C33\u0C35-\u0C39\u0C3D\u0C58\u0C59\u0C60\u0C61\u0C85-\u0C8C\u0C8E-\u0C90\u0C92-\u0CA8\u0CAA-\u0CB3\u0CB5-\u0CB9\u0CBD\u0CDE\u0CE0\u0CE1\u0D05-\u0D0C\u0D0E-\u0D10\u0D12-\u0D28\u0D2A-\u0D39\u0D3D\u0D60\u0D61\u0D7A-\u0D7F\u0D85-\u0D96\u0D9A-\u0DB1\u0DB3-\u0DBB\u0DBD\u0DC0-\u0DC6\u0E01-\u0E30\u0E32\u0E33\u0E40-\u0E45\u0E81\u0E82\u0E84\u0E87\u0E88\u0E8A\u0E8D\u0E94-\u0E97\u0E99-\u0E9F\u0EA1-\u0EA3\u0EA5\u0EA7\u0EAA\u0EAB\u0EAD-\u0EB0\u0EB2\u0EB3\u0EBD\u0EC0-\u0EC4\u0EDC\u0EDD\u0F00\u0F40-\u0F47\u0F49-\u0F6C\u0F88-\u0F8B\u1000-\u102A\u103F\u1050-\u1055\u105A-\u105D\u1061\u1065\u1066\u106E-\u1070\u1075-\u1081\u108E\u10D0-\u10FA\u1100-\u1248\u124A-\u124D\u1250-\u1256\u1258\u125A-\u125D\u1260-\u1288\u128A-\u128D\u1290-\u12B0\u12B2-\u12B5\u12B8-\u12BE\u12C0\u12C2-\u12C5\u12C8-\u12D6\u12D8-\u1310\u1312-\u1315\u1318-\u135A\u1380-\u138F\u13A0-\u13F4\u1401-\u166C\u166F-\u167F\u1681-\u169A\u16A0-\u16EA\u1700-\u170C\u170E-\u1711\u1720-\u1731\u1740-\u1751\u1760-\u176C\u176E-\u1770\u1780-\u17B3\u17DC\u1820-\u1842\u1844-\u1877\u1880-\u18A8\u18AA\u18B0-\u18F5\u1900-\u191C\u1950-\u196D\u1970-\u1974\u1980-\u19AB\u19C1-\u19C7\u1A00-\u1A16\u1A20-\u1A54\u1B05-\u1B33\u1B45-\u1B4B\u1B83-\u1BA0\u1BAE\u1BAF\u1C00-\u1C23\u1C4D-\u1C4F\u1C5A-\u1C77\u1CE9-\u1CEC\u1CEE-\u1CF1\u2135-\u2138\u2D30-\u2D65\u2D80-\u2D96\u2DA0-\u2DA6\u2DA8-\u2DAE\u2DB0-\u2DB6\u2DB8-\u2DBE\u2DC0-\u2DC6\u2DC8-\u2DCE\u2DD0-\u2DD6\u2DD8-\u2DDE\u3006\u303C\u3041-\u3096\u309F\u30A1-\u30FA\u30FF\u3105-\u312D\u3131-\u318E\u31A0-\u31B7\u31F0-\u31FF\u3400-\u4DB5\u4E00-\u9FCB\uA000-\uA014\uA016-\uA48C\uA4D0-\uA4F7\uA500-\uA60B\uA610-\uA61F\uA62A\uA62B\uA66E\uA6A0-\uA6E5\uA7FB-\uA801\uA803-\uA805\uA807-\uA80A\uA80C-\uA822\uA840-\uA873\uA882-\uA8B3\uA8F2-\uA8F7\uA8FB\uA90A-\uA925\uA930-\uA946\uA960-\uA97C\uA984-\uA9B2\uAA00-\uAA28\uAA40-\uAA42\uAA44-\uAA4B\uAA60-\uAA6F\uAA71-\uAA76\uAA7A\uAA80-\uAAAF\uAAB1\uAAB5\uAAB6\uAAB9-\uAABD\uAAC0\uAAC2\uAADB\uAADC\uABC0-\uABE2\uAC00-\uD7A3\uD7B0-\uD7C6\uD7CB-\uD7FB\uF900-\uFA2D\uFA30-\uFA6D\uFA70-\uFAD9\uFB1D\uFB1F-\uFB28\uFB2A-\uFB36\uFB38-\uFB3C\uFB3E\uFB40\uFB41\uFB43\uFB44\uFB46-\uFBB1\uFBD3-\uFD3D\uFD50-\uFD8F\uFD92-\uFDC7\uFDF0-\uFDFB\uFE70-\uFE74\uFE76-\uFEFC\uFF66-\uFF6F\uFF71-\uFF9D\uFFA0-\uFFBE\uFFC2-\uFFC7\uFFCA-\uFFCF\uFFD2-\uFFD7\uFFDA-\uFFDC]/
```

Or you use [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) with its [Unicode plugin](http://xregexp.com/plugins/#unicode) where the previous ranges were taken from.

---

**Edit**    After seeing that you have asked similar question concerning my solution removing too much character, I have to admit that this regular expression does only cover the Unicode letters but not digits or the space. To fix that, just add `0-9`  at the end of the character class above:

```
/[^…0-9 ]/
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps instead of saying "anything that's *not* these specific characters, get rid of", you could instead say "only get rid of a few specific characters"? Thus, something like this instead (but with more punctuation):

```
replace(/[.,!?:;'"-]+/g, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to the other two answers, I'd say that you have a localisation problem and perhaps should use somthing like `[^[:alnum:] ]`. I'm not entirely sure of the syntax here, this is more of an "answer in principle". Anyway any good regexp engine should include all accented characters appropriate to the locale and possibly handle long characters of one kind or another as well.

Comment: I think these POSIX style character classes are not standard but proprietary extensions.

Comment: The POSIX standard *does* state that `[:alnum:]` and friends should be locale-aware, but nobody follows the POSIX standard.  POSIX character classes have been superseded by Unicode properties, but JavaScript doesn't support those, either.  JavaScript is *supposed* to follow the ECMA-262 standard, but that's a mess: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/es3-regexes-broken